# Why doesn't 'encode("utf-8", 'ignore').decode("utf-8")' strip non-UTF8 chars in Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, string, utf-8

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django 2.0.  I want to strip out non-UTF-8 characters from a string, that I'm obtaining by reading this CSV file.  I tried this ...

```
web_site = row['website'].strip().encode("utf-8", 'ignore').decode("utf-8")
```

but this doesn't seem to be doing the job, since I have a resulting string that looks like ...

```
web_site: "wbez.org<200e>"
```

Whatever this "<200e>" thing is, is evidently non-UTF-8 string, because when I try and insert this into a MySQL database (deployed as a docker image), I get the following error ...

```
web_1     | django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture '/app/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': Could not load maps.Coop(pk=191): (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x8E' for column 'web_site' at row 1")
```

Comment: `U+200E` is a `LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `row['website']` is already a Unicode string.  UTF-8 can support all valid Unicode code points, so `.encode('utf8','ignore')` doesn't typically ignore anything and encodes the entire string in UTF-8, and `.decode('utf8')` changes it back to a Unicode string again.

If you simply want to strip non-ASCII characters, use the following to filter only ASCII characters and ignore the rest.

```
row['website'].encode('ascii','ignore').decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Note: UTF-8 encoding won't encode the high/low surrogate pairs used by UTF-16 that Python allows in its `str` type for some reason, so something like `'\ud800\udc00'.encode('utf-8')` will fail with a `UnicodeEncodeError`, while `'\ud800\udc00'.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')` will silently return `b''`. So the OP's code *might* ignore some garbage, but if it's receiving said garbage, it probably indicates a bigger problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hence the “doesn’t typically ignore” wording.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing the encodings.

- Python has a standard character set: Unicode
- UTF-8 is just and encoding of Unicode. All characters in Unicode can be encoded in UTF-8, and all valid UTF-8 codes can be interpreted as unicode characters.

So you are just encoding and decoding Unicode strings, so the code should do nothing. (There is really some exceptional cases: Python strings really are a superset of Unicode, so your code would just remove non Unicode characters, see `surrogateescape`, for such extremely seldom case, usually you will enconter only by reading `sys.argv` or `os.environ`).

In any case, I think you are doing thing wrong. Search in this site for the general question (e.g. "remove non-ascii characters"). It is often better to decompose (with K, compatibility), and then remove accent, and then remove non-ascii characters, so that you will get more characters translated. There are various function to create *slug*, which do a better job, or there is also a library which translate more characters in "nearly equivalent" ascii characters (Unicode has various representation of LETTER A, and you may want to translate also Alpha and Aleph and ... into A (better then discarding, especially if you have a foreign language, which possibly you will discard everything).